# Issue creating Financial Account for Site guest User

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, crud

Unable to Create Financial Account using Site Guest, User even after assign permission set  provide by FSC , Below are the permission sets

Financial Services Cloud Extension
Financial Services Cloud Basic
Financial Services Cloud Standard

Example :

```
financialAccount=new FinServ__FinancialAccount__c();
financialAccount.Name = 'CheckingAccount';
financialAccount.FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c = personAccount.id;
financialAccount.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.FinServ__FinancialAccount__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Checking Account').getRecordTypeId();
insert financialAccount;
```

Execute above code in guest user profile access. Object has create permission for financial account  still it throw  bellow error. i am able to edit any create financial account using wihtout shairng context.

> Exception : |System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Is the Checking Account record type enabled in any of the permission sets?

Comment: @david-cheng Yes, checking account record type permission was given to guest user